# Which language has most advanced support for proof based programming?

Tags: programming-languages, programming-practices, unit-testing

By proof based programming, I mean, you can somehow prove the correctness of your program without testing.

I heard that Ada has a feature called contract, I also heard that, if you can pass Haskell's type checker, your program probably is right.

Can I write correct program without a single line of test code in these two language? Is there other language that supports this kind of feature?

Comment: Any Turing complete language will let you compile code that goes into an infinite loop - which is usually not correct - and conversely any language that guarantees termination isn't Turing complete. There's also no guarantee the code won't throw an exception. That said, there are proof assistants like [Coq](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) that are made for proving properties about code and can produce executable Haskell source code. On that note, one of the reasons people say that about Haskell is that it's pure, so it keeps code with side effects separate from pure code.

Comment: Some languages have conventions and tools to help proofs. E.g. if you code in a suitable subset of C and add ACSL annotations in `/*@` comments for [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) you could sometimes have some proof support.

Answer (score 12):

It's not exactly clear what you are asking.

You can always prove a program correct, if you want. This is independent of the language.

The question is, can you get the computer to do the proof for you, or at least *check* a proof given by you? And the answer is: Yes!

In fact, the Curry-Howard-Isomorphism states that there is an isomorphism between logic and programming, between proofs and programs, between theorems and types. Every type is a theorem (and vice versa), every program is a proof (and vice versa). So, in some sense, *every* statically typed language does this; every type checker is a theorem prover!

However, there is a limit to what you can express in a type. Haskell lets you express more than, say, Java, but there is even more. In a dependently-typed language, static types may depend on runtime values. For example, there could be a type `List<n>` which is a list with `n` elements, where `n` is a value that is only determined at runtime.

Now, in order to type-check such a program, the type checker needs to be able to statically prove properties about runtime values, but we all know that this lets us run quickly into the Halting Problem. Well, dependently-typed languages have a simple solution: they don't allow non-termination, they are *total*, i.e. they *always* terminate, therefore the Halting Problem doesn't apply.

Obviously, that means that they aren't Turing-complete, but that sounds scarier than it actually is. Firstly, there are many languages that aren't Turing-complete, yet still useful: regex, SQL (before 2003), HTML+CSS (before HTML5+CSS3), and many others. In fact, since the C spec requires that I can take the address of any object and the size of any object, and both of those have to fit into a finite sized integer, C is technically not Turing-complete, because it doesn't have infinite memory. Likewise, our computers aren't Turing-complete either, in fact, it is physically impossible to build a Turing-complete computing machine.

But that's hair-splitting, there are much more practical considerations. For example, one might think that an operating system, a web server, or really anything with an event loop can't be built with a language that isn't Turing-complete. But it turns out that instead of modeling, say, an operating system as an infinite loop (or rather infinite recursion) over data, we can also model it using *finite* co-recursion over co-data! And in fact, there are many such patterns for problems that at first glance might require an infinite loop or non-terminating recursion.

Dependently-typed languages fall into three broad camps:

- (Interactive) Proof Assistants: these are programs that are primarily designed for computer-assisted proofs. The fact that one can also program in them is rather incidental.
- Dependently-typed languages: these are primarily intended as programming languages, the language itself typically doesn't offer any tools to ease the "proof"-part.
- Integrated approaches, where the IDE for the language contains an interactive proof assistant that helps you with constructing the proof(s) while you are constructing the program, similarly to how a modern IDE with visual interactive debugging, profiling etc. helps you with constructing programs.

Some of those languages/proof systems are (in no particular order):

- [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/)
- [ATS](http://ats-lang.org)
- [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/)
- [Epigram2](http://e-pig.org/)
- [Guru](https://code.google.com/archive/p/guru-lang/)
- [Idris](http://idris-lang.org/)
- [Isabelle/HOL](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/)
- [Matita](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Matita)
- [NuPRL](http://nuprl.org/)
- [Twelf](http://twelf.org/)

Of those, Coq is the most mature. It was, however, clearly not designed for programming. When viewed as a programming language, it isn't actually a very nice one.

OTOH, Idris is somewhat new, but it is clearly designed as programming language. It is very much like Haskell. You could think of it as Haskell-with-dependent-types.

ATS is unlike the others. It is not a full dependent-typed language / proof assistant. Rather it is being designed as a systems programming language, as a replacement for C, C++, D, Java, C# and similar languages with performance comparable to C, and "just enough dependent typing to prove some interesting properties". ATS is not geared towards being able to prove everything but rather specific safety properties of software systems such as operating systems, compilers, servers, etc.

Comment: I didn't know about this close relationship of types and proofs, after reading this answer I found this article that can be interesting: "Types in Programming Languages, between Modelling, Abstraction, and Correctness” by Simone Martini. http://www.cs.unibo.it/~martini/papers-to-ftp/Cie-revised.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

1. The proof doesn't know what you want to accomplish with your code.  That's the domain of  well-written software requirements.
2. Tests (when used as a description of requirements, as in TDD) are proof of the software requirements, not the software itself.
3. The proof can, and often does, exceed the complexity of the actual program.  Proofs, unlike tests, must account for all possible edge cases.
4. Some things you can't prove or predict.  Things like the customer saying "This isn't what I actually wanted."

All that said, Haskell is probably the closest thing to "programming by proof."

Rather than asking for an iron-clad guarantee, good language designers (as well as good programmers) seek to make software more reliable by reducing complexity as much as possible.  This reduces (but does not eliminate) the number of edge-cases, which is what we're really after.

Comment: `2. Tests are proof of the software requirements. No tests, no proof.` Tests are not correctness proofs. They show that the code is correct/incorrect for a small subset of all inputs, but a correctness proof usually shows correctness for all inputs. Normally I wouldn't be that pedantic about it, but the OP did explicitly mention proofs.

Comment: @Doval: I was referring to the narrow case where the tests *are* the requirements.  I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Just want to mention Isabelle/HOL. A quick search leads to this paper http://isabelle.in.tum.de/~haftmann/pdf/from_hol_to_haskell_haftmann.pdf